# Intersection of 2 events, Independence

Tags: probability

If $B$ and $C$ are two independent events, and $A$ is an event, what can we say about the independence of $B \cap A$ and $C$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**1:** The events $B\cap A$ and $C$ **need not be independent**.

For example, toss a fair coin twice.  Let $B$ be the event "head on first toss" and let$C$ be the event "head on second."  Then $B$ and $C$ are independent.

Let $A=C$ be the event "head on second." Then the event $B\cap A$ is head on both tosses.

The events  $B\cap A$ and $C$ are not independent, since $\Pr(C|B\cap A)=1$, while $\Pr(C)=1/2$.

**2:** The events $B\cap A$ and $C$ **can be independent**. For example, if we make all the events the same, with each having probability $1$, we get independence. For another kind of example, toss a fair coin $3$ times. Let $A, B, C$ be respectively "head on first toss," "head on second," and "head on third."